# Need help in handling asynch calls using. Anyone suggestions on writing Observable using Vertx3-EventBus and angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, vert.x

Can anyone suggest on writing Observables using EventBus in Angular? Tried many ways to do this and failing. I'm having a very hard time to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Service.

```
import * as EventBus from 'vertx3-eventbus-client';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";


export class Login {

    res: any = {};
    login(user: any): Observable<any>{
        var eb = new EventBus('http://localhost:40400/auction');
        eb.enableReconnect(true);
        eb.onopen = function () {
         };
        eb.enableReconnect(true);
          return eb.send(s.REGISTER, user, (error, reply) => {
                console.log("reply:"+ JSON.stringify(reply));
                this.res = reply;
            //    observer.next(this.res);
                }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
            // return Observable.create(observer => {
            //     console.log("this.res:" + JSON.stringify(this.res));
            //     observer.next(this.res);
            //    })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for this, a few years ago I made a small demo about using the eventbus and react, in this case I bind the eventbus to react's state, see this presentation, from slide 22 to 25:

https://www.jetdrone.xyz/presentations/codemotion-amsterdam-2017/#/22

The important code is here:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount() {
    Rx.Observable
      .create((observer) => {
        eb.registerHandler('greetings', (err, msg) => {
          observer.next(msg.body.msg);
        });
      })
      .subscribe(message => {
        this.state.messages.unshift(message);
        this.setState({ messages: this.state.messages });
      });
  }
```

Of course lots of things changed since then and for **Angular** you probably want to use ngrx and for that there's a full article describing how to use it here:

https://vertx.io/blog/building-a-real-time-web-app-with-angular-ngrx-and-vert-x/